# Bulk Insert performance in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, bulkinsert, odac

I tried lot of solutions but I still don't understand something: i got a simple insert (with 40 columns of different kind (blob included) and i try to insert this kind of data passing (I use Odac from c#) arrays of values for each parameter.

The result is a single invoke of ExecuteNonQuery for 4000rows more or less, the problem is that this insert with no so much of element last 3hours.

Any suggestion? the data source is from the software so can't be linked on db, its memory data and all I do is put them in arrays and pass them as input parameters of my oraclecommand that I then run.

Will in this case use a storedprocedure make any difference? why?

The insert actually is in a transaction but there's no index at all in the table i try to insert into, the db its a regular installation of Oracle XE with 100 tables, transaction includes just this insert and few other actions not so big.
Total data i try to insert are 100 Mb max... I dont know what should I check again :(

Again: the transaction seems not affecting performance and the speed isnt linear, ie 1000elements =10minutes, 4000element=3hours..all with cpu 100% and a huge use of memory

Comment: Care to post what you have tried so we can eliminate / investigate solutions and reasons?

Comment: A few possibilities: 1. complex/many indexes that need to be updated after each insert (consider disabling during insert + recreating afterwards) 2. on-insert triggers that are triggered after each inserted row

Comment: are u committing in your transaction?  eg => OracleTransaction trans ... cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); trans.Commit(); trans.Dispose();  Is the procedure doing a commit?

Comment: Thanks, at the end of post some more detail but actually no index, no complicated situations...just trying know without transactions to check if is there the problem but of course i really need transactions in the real world...

Comment: Another information: during the process seems the critical aspect is CPU, its all the time on 100% during the execution of insert query

Answer (score 1):

Inserting 4,000 rows takes 3 hours? Is that the problem? Unless each row is a several GBs long, there's no real excuse for such performance - you need to look at the database (or have your DBA do it), and not your C# code.

Comment: he has blobs which can be huge. The transfer may take much time.

Comment: Thanks, but actually the DB its a regular oracle XE (version 10) without any problem...what should I check in your opinion on DB?